# printing method class randTest (int n)

Tags: java, random, methods, printf

I am having trouble printing out the method randTest (int n) as errors keep appearing. I want to print this method in the main as i want to print the results in a clear tabular form. The method must stay static void. This is my code below:

```
public class RandNumGenerator {

    public static int RandInt(){
        double n = Math.random()*10;
        return (int) n;
        }

    public static void randTest(int n){
        int [] counts = new int [10];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            counts[i] = RandInt();
            System.out.println(counts[i]);
            } 
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RandInt());
        System.out.println(randTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(randTest());` 2 errors in the line

Comment: What are the errors? What are they trying to tell you? You appears to be trying to print the result of a method which returns `void`.  Perhaps you intended this method to return something like the `counts`  BTW To print an `int[]` you need to use `Arrays.toString(counts)` as the default toString() is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the method `randTest()` instead of printing it. The work of printing is already done inside the method. And `randTest` takes in an argument of the type int. So, you need to save the return of `RandInt` and then pass it into the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randInt = RandInt();
        System.out.println(randInt);
        randTest(randInt);
}
```